2D Modified Random Walk
A particle starts at the point $\left(0,0\right)$:

It can move $+1$ to the right with a probability $p$,
it can move $+1$ up with a probability $q$,
and it can move diagonally up and to the right with probability $r$.

So it can take steps of size $\left(0,1\right),\ \left(1,0\right)$ or
$\left(1,1\right)$.



Has this problem been looked at before ?.
Is there any preexisting work done somebody can link me to ?.

When you say "problem", I think that you want to express the probabilities for the moving point to be in such or such position after $n$ steps.
The classical technique for this kind of issue is to consider  the  bivariate generating function which is here the bivariate polynomial :
$$f(x,y)=px+qy+rxy=px^1y^0+qx^0y^1+rx^1y^1\tag{1}$$
The $n$th step being obtained by taking this polynomial at the power $n$, followed by an "extraction" of he probabilities as the coefficients of the monomials $ax^py^q$, $a$ being the probability for the moving point to be in position $(p,q)$ after $n$ steps.
Let us illustrate it on the elementary case of power $n=2$ :
$$f(x,y)^n=p^2x^2y^0+q^2x^0y^2+r^2x^2y^2+2pqx^1y^1+2prx^2y^1+2qrx^1y^2$$
For example, considering

monomial $p^2x^2y^0$, there is a probability $p^2$ that the moving point is in position $(2,0)$ after two steps (which is true),

monomial $q^2x^0y^2$, there is a probability $q^2$ that the moving point is in position $(0,2)$ after two steps (which is true),


etc.
What has been done for $2$ steps can evidently be done for $n$ steps...
The figures below display, for a given $n$, the reached "sites" with their associated probabilities in the case $n=6$.

Fig. 1 : Case $n=6$ for particular values $p=\tfrac12,q=\tfrac13,r=\tfrac16$ (Sage program below).

Fig. 2 : Case $n=6$ for general values of $p,q,r$.
Different observations can be made on Fig. 2 (all these "observations" have a proof...) :

the "reachable" sites constitute a triangle.

each "reachable" site is reached in a unique manner in $n$ steps.

the upmost row of coefficients is the $n$th row of Pascal triangle, here, for $n=6$, the list $1,6,15,20,15,6,1$.

Considering coefficients columnwise, one sees that there is also a "Pascal triangle" behind : for example the 3rd column $20,60,60,20$ is obtainable by multiplying the third row of the Pascal triangle $1,3,3,1$ by $20$, otherwise said, all the coefficients are products of 2 binomial coefficients ; the general formula for the monomial in position $(X,Y)$ can be shown to be in the triangular domain $X+Y \ge n,X \le n, Y \le n$ :


$$p_{X,Y}=\binom{n-Y}{X}\binom{X}{n}p^{n-Y}q^{n-X}r^{X+Y-n}\tag{2}$$
Remarks :

In formula (2) above, the total exponent is $n$, independently from $X,Y$.

From (1), one can derive the following general formula gathering the different values of $n$ :


$$g(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(x,y)^n=\frac{1}{1-f(x,y)}=\frac{1}{1-px-qy-rxy}$$

For a combinatorial point of view (without a probabilistic context), see the correspondence with Delannoy paths/numbers for example here or there or with Pell numbers.

Here is the "Sage" program (a public domain CAS) which has generated the 2 figures (the first one being obtained by un-commenting the 4th line) :
A.<p,q,r>=QQ[] # A = coefficients' ring
B.<x,y>=A[] # ring of polynomials in x,y with coeff. in A
n=6
#p=1/2;q=1/3;r=1/6
f=p*x+q*y+r*x*y
g=Graphics()
F=f^n
Fc=F.coefficients()
Fm=F.monomials()
for k in range(len(Fm)) :
    u=Fm[k]
    e=u.exponents()
    g+=text(Fc[k],e[0],fontsize=7)
show(g)


Thank you! I am also interested in what the large limit looks like; it should converge to some 2D Gaussian I imagime.

Thanks. I just added a graphical representation evidencing the fact that the domains are triangular ; therefore the possible connection with a Gaussian distribution will at least necessitate an adaptation.

@Letac Gérard Thanks for refering to the well-written book 'Principles of Random Walk' by Frank Spitzer, but I am unable to spot in this book where this kind of random walk is considered.
